# STS / Spring Boot - Running Spring Boot Project inside IDE is using test dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, flyway

Test Dependencies in `build.gradle`,

```
testCompile('org.flywaydb:flyway-core')
testCompile('org.hsqldb:hsqldb')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

When i run the application as `Spring Boot App`, i get error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema [dbo] without metadata table! Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the metadata table.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    ...
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema [dbo] without metadata table! Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the metadata table.
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1035) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 more
```

Why the test dependencies are used while running the project inside IDE?
Or i am missing something here?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**NOTE:**

1 - It runs fine if i run it outside the IDE using `java -jar [put path here]` or gradle boot run

2 - I have tried refresh gradle project, clean project etc.

3 - Using STS Version `3.8.3.RELEASE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with Gradle Eclipse support. It has been a problem for as long as I can remember. It is a problem in STS legacy support for Gradle and it is still a problem in BuildShip as well.

Since STS legacy support is under 'low maintenance' mode it isn't likely to be getting a fix there. But in BuildShip there is hope. There was a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482315) open for this in Eclipse bugzilla. The bug recently [got moved](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/354) to github.

I suggest you head over to the github issue and add your voice / vote there.

Comment: thank you for the information.  Added vote there. Accepted as answer and waiting for fix. Hope they do something about it soon :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess : your hsql database is persistant and has not been initialize by Flyway and the database/schema 'dbo' already has some tables created ?

Comment: No tables exists. It has test dependency. Which i think implies that, those `jar`s should not be used while running the application. It should only get used when i run tests.